# How to change javascript option on resizing window?

Tags: javascript, media-queries, jquery-events, jquery-isotope, window-resize

I need to have an option in my script changed when I resize my window down to 500px for mobile devices. Must be simple but I could not manage it. I need `fitWidth: true` to be 'false' when the window size is for example 500px.

Here is the code:

```
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('#container').isotope({
itemSelector: '.element',
masonry: {
columnWidth: '.element',
fitWidth: true,
horizontalOrder: true
},
filter: function() {
var $this = $(this);
var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
return searchResult && buttonResult;
}
});
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You can always attach a CSS class to your element, then use media queries inside your CSS file to adjust as needed.

Comment: you can create a responsive page with the help of css.

Answer (score 1):

use the onresize event

```
window.onresize = function() {
  if (screen.width <= 500) {
   console.log("do something");
  }
}
```

Comment: could you provide an example on 'do something' since I cant manage it. simply turn 'fitWidth' into false please

Comment: I'm not familiar with isotope. from a quick look, I was not able to reassign a new value to fitWidth (because of the idea of caching it? idk). but what worked was reassigning $grid with the whole stuff (incl. `fitWidth: false`